# facebook app working on emulator not on device(fberror:the server failed to communicate.Try again later)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have tried everything possible but it does not work on my htc device.

facebookError ::the server failed to communicate.Try again later

Source: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included the internet permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Hi baconcheese113.I have included that else I would not be logging in.This error is after I type in username and password.

Comment: Did you try Exporting a Signed apk, and running that?

Comment: I tried it but I don't know the exact procedure to export signed app for facebook.How do  get the hash key for exporting? Is it the same as debugging ? If you can shed some more light on the process It would be great.

Comment: It's fairly simple. Right click on your project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package... Then follow the wizard.

Comment: I checked that it did not work, What about the hash key in facebook developer api do I need to change anything?

Comment: If the emulator works and logs into your account correctly then you must have set up your Facebook App correctly. Either way, the best thing would probably be to run through the tutorial again.

Comment: Yes I have done all possible scenarios but I still get (fberror:the server failed to communicate.Try again later) on the device.